# Firebase Phone Auth Resend SMS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

With the javascript api, is there a way to 'resend' the verifcation sms text for Firebase SMS? I can't find a solution for javascript

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call `firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)`, Firebase will send an SMS to verify that the user has access to that phone number.

See the [Firebase guide on sending a verification code to the user's phone](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone) and the [reference guide on `signInWithPhoneNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithPhoneNumber).

Comment: so I guess your saying, the solution to resending is to recall